# WebView2 creation failed with exception = System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'WebView2Loader.dll'

Tags: asp.net-web-api, webview2

I'm trying to use [WebView2](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) in ASP.Net Web API Web App (VS2019).
The WebView2 package is installed using NuGet Package Manager.
I see the `runtimes` subfolder with all the needed runtimes in my web app's `\bin` folder.
But I'm getting a run-time error message:

```
WebView2 creation failed with exception = System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'WebView2Loader.dll': 
  The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
  at Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment.CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions(String browserExecutableFolder, String userDataFolder, ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions options, ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler environment_created_handler)
  at Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment.<CreateAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
```

The run-time error happens at the last line of the following code:

```
var webView = new Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2();
...
var ecwTask = webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
```

AFAICG I should try to create a custom [CoreWebView2Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2environment?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1150.38) and pass it as parameter to `webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(...)`.

Any ideas how it can be done or how to solve the subject issue differently?

Comment: You must install the runtime too: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/

Comment: @Paul Bak : I have  WebView2 runtime installed - the WinForms and Console .NET apps using WebView2 are working well with `var ecwTask = webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null)`

Comment: I just noticed: `ASP.Net Web API`. `WebView2` is not for Asp.net, it is for Winforms as you have seen. Remember asp.net has no user interface, so it can't display `WebView2`. If you want your asp.net server to fetch urls, then you should use `HttpClient`.

Comment: @Paul Back: You can use `MS WebView2 control` Automation *without user interface* in the .NET Framework Console applications so I suppose `MS WebView2 control` should also work in ASP.NET apps. The only current issue I have is that ASP.NET app can't find `WebView2Loader.dll`. I guess that the path to `WebView2Loader.dll` is somehow related not to the location of the ASP.NET app executables but on the `Identity` under which the ASP.NET app is running.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the subject issue ("Unable to load DLL 'WebView2Loader.dll'") with the following code:

```
var udf = ... // Temp Folder - should be new for every new instance of WebView2 control  
var fixedDriverFolder = null;  
var envTask = await Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment  
        .CreateAsync(browserExecutableFolder: fixedDriverFolder, userDataFolder: udf);  

var ecwTask =  br.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(envTask);  
while (ecwTask.IsCompleted == false)  
{  
    Application.DoEvents();  
};
```

Now I can use WebView2 Control in .NET Framework console applications.
I still can't use the WebView2 control in ASP.NET Web Api Web App - another runtime error appears.